# 3d model is shown only blue color Unity-VuforiaSDK

Tags: android, unity-game-engine, vuforia, 3d-model

I have a unity scene that contains a 2d marker and 3d target. It works properly on editor, but not on android.

On andoid phone, when the app recognizes the marker, I can only blue model in fullscreen.

I use [this package](https://www.assetstore.unity3d.com/en/#!/content/13925) from unity asset store. How can I solve this problem?

Phone screenshot :

[image]

Comment: That is a normal map. Something seems to use the normal map for albedo map.

Comment: I create a new scene. It works now, but I don't understand how fix it.

Comment: You probably dragged the normal map into the albedo map of your material.